# SQL SP: How to return one inactive record along with active records

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, having

I am working on this peculiar sql stored proc where the business case is as follows:

**Business Case:**
Table Specialties contains all the Specialties and there is a bit field for each record telling if it's Active or Inactive. We always display only the active records from that table in form of dropdown. Users may select a Specialty which can later on be deactivated. New requirement is to be able to pull that Inactive record along with all the active records in the result set.

**Here's how I thought I should do this:**
If no specialty is assigned to the person I am pulling up then the dropdown is going to be populated by all active records.
If there is a inactive specialty associated with the person I am pulling up then I send that specialtyID in stored proc as a parameter and return that inactive records along with active records to populate the dropdown.

**Below is what I got so far:**
So far if I dont pass in any specialtyId then I am returning active specialty records which is working. When I send in a specialtyId  parameter then it just returns that one inactive record but not rest of the other active records. I need the rest of the active records too along with that one inactive record.

```
   DECLARE  @specialtyId  INT = null;
  BEGIN
    IF isnull(@specialtyId,'')=''
      BEGIN
        SELECT SpecialtyID AS Id, Specialty AS Name
          FROM dbo.Specialties
         WHERE IsActive = 1
         ORDER BY Specialty;
      END
    ELSE 
      BEGIN
        SET @specialtyId = @specialtyId ;

        SELECT s.SpecialtyID AS Id, s.Specialty AS Name
          FROM dbo.Specialties s
         WHERE specialtyId = @specialtyId
         GROUP BY s.Specialty, s.SpecialtyID
         HAVING (Specialty IS NOT NULL)
            AND (max(SpecialtyID) IS NOT NULL)
         ORDER BY Name;
      END
  END
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Their sp's aren't compatible...

Comment: What is this supposed to do: SET specialtyId = specialtyId; ??

(removed @'s because of mentioning in comments)

Comment: isnull(specialtyId,'')='' You're comparing an INT value with an empty string?

Comment: @Jens thanks for pointing that out. I will fix that! :)

Comment: Note: Cross-posted to the [Database Administrators' stack](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/150772/116653).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that this can be done with no `IF` whatsoever:

```
SELECT  s.SpecialtyID AS Id, 
        s.Specialty AS Name
FROM dbo.Specialties s
WHERE specialtyID = @specialtyId
OR IsActive = 1;
```

Comment: Ya but the above is just going to return just one inactive record in case SpecialtyID is supplied. I need active records returned as well as that one inactive record for which we supplied the specialtyID

Comment: @HereToLearn_ No, that's not how it works. Did you try it?

Comment: yes I tried it and it just returned me one record when I passed a specialtyId which is Inactive. @Lamak

Comment: @HereToLearn_ And does that specialtyId have any active rows?

Comment: SpecialtyID's are unique in this case primary key. The specific SpecialtyID I sent as parameter was an Inactive specialty. I need it to return that inactive specialty along with active records. I would be using this list to populate a dropdown.

Comment: @HereToLearn_ Updated my answer for your last comment, but that wasn't the same as I understood your question

Comment: wow.... how come I did not think of this lol. Thanks so much! I was thinking this was gonna be super complicated. This was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all in the where clause. In the case below it checks to see if the @specId is pass in and selects only that ID or Inactive records OR if the @specId is 0 then just select the active records.

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmptest') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tmptest
CREATE TABLE #tmptest
(
    SpecialtyID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    , SpecialtyName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    , IsActive BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT (0)
)

INSERT INTO #tmptest
VALUES 
    ('Peditrician', 1)
    , ('Rad Tech', 1)
    , ('Surg Nurse', 1)
    , ('Peds Nurse', 1)
    , ('Cardio Doctor', 0)
    , ('Cardio Nurse', 1)
    , ('Test Doctor', 1)

DECLARE @SpecID INT = 0

SELECT *
FROM #tmptest
WHERE 
    ( 
        (@SpecID > 0 AND (SpecialtyID = @SpecID OR IsActive = 0))
        OR
        (@SpecID = 0 AND IsActive = 1)
    )
```